# F#: How to test internal modules from another project?

Tags: .net-core, f#

I follow the best F# practices from [.Net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-fsharp-with-mstest):

- I create a project for the Application (console, not library)
- I create a project for the Tests (with Expecto but doesn't matter)

Problem: Some of my Application modules are not exposed via the `internal` keyword. Thus I cannot import these modules in my Tests project.

=> How can I perform unit testing of these modules? Should I remove the internal access control?

Thanks!

Comment: You should test only public interface. So if you have internal modules, they should be tested via public modules that uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test `internal`, you can use `InternalsVisibleTo`, to test private classes, you can link the files in your test project (when you are in the "add file" dialog, you can select link, instead of open).

However, as already has been commented, generally you would only test the public interface. But occasionally you want to separately test complex internals as well. For instance in the .NET runtime libraries, this is often done (there are a lot of complex internals), and they use the linking approach a lot.

Since private really means private to the class, and you won't even be able to access such members from an extension method, you should put such members in their own private class, as public members. That way, when you link, the class is accessible, and the members as well, but neither are accessible in your production version.

Use this technique sparingly, because it will bind your private details to the test system, and you won't be as free to change the internal implementation.